# Laravel Apache two or more project on developer machine

Tags: php, laravel, apache, server, virtualhost

I have two laravel project on developer machine, this machine just only have the 80 port enabled. How could I mount two or more proyect with apache? this is I need:

example in browser should be:

```
       10.20.30.40/project1 
       10.20.30.40/project2
       10.20.30.40/project3
       ...
```

I have configured these virtual hosts on apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.20.30.40
    ServerAlias 10.20.30.40/project1
    ServerPath /project1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/project1/public>
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/project1/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/project1/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 10.20.30.40
    ServerAlias 10.20.30.40/project2
    ServerPath /project2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project2/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/project2/public>
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/project2/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/project2/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

but not working... Any Help?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to run same project on different ports?

Comment: Umar. are different projects on same port, but with /project1, /project2 etc

Comment: Do you want it using apache or using php artisan serve command will do?

Comment: apache virtual host

Answer (score 0):

Your ServerName and ServerAlias (optional) need to be unique to each virtual host. You should define project1 and project2 in your /etc/hosts file (assuming Linux or Mac) and set ServerName attributes to match. I don't think you need ServerAlias or ServerPath. It sounds like you should define project1 and project2 in your /etc/hosts file, like this:

```
10.20.30.40        project1
10.20.30.40        project2
```

then in your apache config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/project1/public>
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/project1/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/project1/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project2/public
    <Directory /var/www/html/project2/public>
    AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/project2/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/project2/log/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This assumes that access would be only from localhost. If you need others to access this, they'll have to point those "domains" one way or another depending on how your network is set up and if they are LAN or WAN.

Comment: many users access this server ... it would be a headache to modify the hosts file of each one. I think it is better to give them a url: like  10.20.30.40/project1 or  10.20.30.40/project2.... if is possible

Comment: So if urls like that are OK, I don't think that you are looking for virtual hosts. In the simplest case you would just have a default server setup, and when they go to 10.20.30.40/project1, they would be in the directory /var/www/html/project1, but you want them in /var/www/html/project1/public. So maybe you could use mod_alias or mod_rewrite for this?